# report of energy data

Tags: mysql, php

I have a mysql Db with energy meter readings in table data_rr
date, gasTot, Solar, toGrid, frGrid etc

All values are updated every 5 minutes and are normaly increasing.

The table spans from now till about one year ago.  I like to generate a report with

```
1) Day values - today and the last 7 days
2) week values - this week and last 4 weeks
3) month values - this month and the last 12 months
```

For the fields GAstot Solar toGrid FrGrid

Can this be done in PHP-mysql? what is the best (fastest) aproach?
thnks

Comment: Post some sample data and desired output in a tabular form

Comment: You should be able to do it with relatively simple pivot-based queries.  Can you show us if anything you HAVE attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it cam be done in many ways ! Reports can be generated using [Reportico](http://www.reportico.org/site/index.php). an free tool used for reportig purpuses.
But thinking of performance is important to know the amount of data you have in your database.
If you have lot's of data you need to partition you tables for better performance.
 I think for a better answer you need to give some more information ! such as database size some data model info as well ! Is the data only historical , do you suffer lots of updates ?
 The query you wrote will attend you well !"

Comment: I have a lot of data every 5minutes a set of data. I was looking at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf50/4 and experimenting with this approach. Is there maybe already simalar php report I can use? or what could be a setup for day week month?

Comment: How mush data are you talking about in GB ?

Comment: The examples in sqlfiddle are working nice but my mysql is 5.6 and I can't figger out what the reason is. These fiddler approaches almost met my wishes.

Comment: I mean examples are written for mysql 2008 not mysql 5.6.

Comment: @Henry the specific SQL fiddles were written using CTEs (Common Table Expressions) which are not available on MySQL. So they will not run in your machine as is.

Comment: As Up_one suggested is reportico a nice suggestion to make the report but now the approach in mySQl 5.6. How do I get the diff of several fields between the last and the first entry of today, yesterday, this week, last week, this month, last month? Do you have a suggestion or a link to where somebody explained how to do that. thnks